# Variable in @section name

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I want to use a variable for my `@section` name like this:

```
@section("{{$variable}}")
@show
```

And then extend that section in my view:

```
@section('variableValue')
    some content... 
@stop
```

It doesn't work. No errors, but the section **does not have my variable's name** and I therefore can't extend it in my view. Any ideas?

Comment: you must call value of your variable, not your name of variable.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I actually do that, was just a typo. edited.

Comment: Why do I get downvoted? I believe this is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take out the "{{ and }}" and make sure the variable name exists and it will work.

or use this :

```
public function anything ($id)
{
      $data = array('childTemplate' => 'yourChildTemplateName');
      return View::make('parent.template')->with($data);
}
```

and then in your blade :

```
@section('menu')
    @include($childTemplate)
@stop
```

Comment: how abot just delete the curly brace and double quote ? I edited it.

Comment: You are right, I was dumb enough to use the curly braces. Removing them did the trick. Thanks :)